# A bunch of m's and p's

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

**What's the answer hidden in the puzzle below?**

---

```
                                  3 m 2 m 1 = 0
                 
                                  9 m 3 m 2 m 1 = 3

                                  1 p 5 m 0 p 5 = 1

                                 (1 p 5)(8)(1 p 5)(1 p 5) = 27 

                                 (3 p 5)(4) = 14

                                 (4 p 5)(8) = 36

                                 10 m 2 m 3 p 5 m 4 = 1/2

                                 (1 p 2)(5)(1 p 5) m 7 = 2

                                  7 p 5 m 6 = 3/2

                                  8 m 4 = 4

                                 (3 p 2)(5)(2 p 5) = 40

                                 17 m 9 m 2 m 1 = 5

                                 16 m 13 p 5 = 5/2
  
                                (2 p 5)(8)(1 p 5)(1 p 4) = 42
```

Comment: @newQOpenWid No need. The knowledge required is something most ppl here are familiar with.

Comment: @newQOpenWid you don't have to voice your discontentment with every puzzle you can't solve (ie all of them) you can just be silent.

Comment: @caPNCApn sorry if I sound rude or whiney, i'm recently not in a very good mood and kind of irritable. and my comment was not because I am making an excuse, it's because inherently I'm not a big fan of [tag:knowledge] puzzles.

Comment: The reason why I don't solve any puzzles recently is because 1. I don't have the time to do deep dives (often questions are both asked and answered when I'm dozing) or the experience and intuition to pick up the answer quickly, and 2. I'm very picky about the types of puzzles I attempt, heavily leaning on [tag:logical-deduction]. I'm lashing out because whenever I see certain tags or types of question, (due to previous experiences with bad puzzles off the site, like the ones offered by clickbait Youtubers), I'm immediately prebiased against it and sometimes just downvote without thinking.

Comment: @newQOpenWid If you're not a fan of [tag:knowledge] puzzles, may I humbly suggest you just not visit them? The tagging  system is there to allow people who like a type of puzzle to seek it out specifically—or, conversely, to purposefully avoid a type they do not like. Feel free to take advantage of this handy SE feature, and find puzzles of more interest to you. Meanwhile, please try not to yuck someone else's yum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Partial answer.

> The pattern of Ms and Ps in each line spell out `morseequations` in Morse. It turns out that the lines are equations where `m` is a **m**inus sign and `p` is a decimal **p**oint.

The choice of figures in each line is somewhat suspicious (ranging from 0 to 17) but I don't know what to make of them.

Comment: Well done! This is actually it. The choice of numbers were irrelevant. Just there for you to figure out which symbol to replace the m or p with.

Comment: A missed opportunity, if you ask me. :P